# connecting to api with curl and display

Tags: php, curl

I'm connecting to traileraddicts api but when I load the page over to server I get this message.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /heima/sth132/.public_html/Lokaverkefnireal/php/trailers.php on line 20 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /heima/sth132/.public_html/Lokaverkefnireal/php/trailers.php on line 20

here's my code and could you guys help me how to fix this???

```
<?php 
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.traileraddict.com/?featured=yes&count=8");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

// load the previously downloaded XML page
$upcoming = simplexml_load_string($output);

foreach($upcoming->trailer as $x => $updates) 
{ 
   echo $updates->title; 
   echo '<br>'; 
   echo '<span style="font-size:x-small">Source: <a href="'. $updates->link .'">TrailerAddict</a></span>'; 
   echo '<br>'; 
   //now echo the embedded trailer 
   echo $updates->embed; 
   echo '<br><br>';     

    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your curl url protocol from `https` to `http`

```
// set url
//please remove https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.traileraddict.com/?featured=yes&count=8");
```

Comment: @jonjonson what error your are getting? Because I have debugged it and got resolution by above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problems seems to come from the URL your are curling, try change https to http, this worked for me

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.traileraddict.com/?featured=yes&count=8");
```